# Matcher problem. Mathcher picks up result through one, and the first position may differ from time to time, Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, download, matcher

There is a site https://m.imdb.com/list/ls000984564/. I'm trying to get all names of actors from there (there are 35 of them). I found the pattern that allows me to perform this work but the problem is that I can add only the half of all possible names into my ArrayList through the one, and the first element can differ from time to time. So one time I can get 1,3,5,...,35 names and other time 2,4,6,...,34 names but never all of them at the same time. What do I do wrong? The code is below.

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "https://m.imdb.com/list/ls000984564/";

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(str);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                StringBuilder htmlCode = new StringBuilder();

                while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null)
                    htmlCode.append(bufferedReader.readLine());

                urlConnection.disconnect();

                ArrayList<String> actorsNamesList = new ArrayList<>();
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<h4>(.*?)</h4>");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlCode.toString());

                while (matcher.find())
                    actorsNamesList.add(matcher.group(1));

                for (String name : actorsNamesList)
                    System.out.println(name);

                System.out.println("Size of a list: " + actorsNamesList.size());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

One of possible results:

```
Leonardo DiCaprio
Gary Oldman
Johnny Depp
Denzel Washington
Russell Crowe
Robert Downey Jr.
George Clooney
Josh Brolin
Paul Rudd
James Franco
Will Smith
Joseph Gordon-Levitt
Jack Nicholson
Stanley Tucci
Jamie Foxx
Tommy Lee Jones
Eric Bana
Jon Hamm
Size of a list: 18
```

Another one that I'm fequently getting in Android Studio:

```
2019-12-07 02:22:20.837 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Christian Bale
2019-12-07 02:22:20.837 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Mark Wahlberg
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Matt Damon
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Daniel Day-Lewis
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Steve Carell
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Edward Norton
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Brad Pitt
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Ryan Reynolds
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Geoffrey Rush
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Ken Watanabe
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Aaron Eckhart
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Clive Owen
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Will Ferrell
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Benicio Del Toro
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: James Gandolfini
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Josh Hartnett
2019-12-07 02:22:20.838 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Greg Kinnear
2019-12-07 02:22:20.840 13840-13840/com.rumato.gratestfilmamericanlegends I/URL: Size: 17
```

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for parsing HTML. You can try a library built specifically for this purpose. such as https://jsoup.org

Comment: If page content is dynamically generated from javascript, you could use HtmlUnit to load it, wait for javascript processing to complete, then use XPath to find what you need.

Comment: Thanks for resource, but it is inetesting for me to find the reason why it add results through the one and why the results can differ from time to time becaus I can't find a mistake.

Comment: Thanks, boot-and-bonnet, I'll try.